# Tube amp: What do these resistors do?

Tags: amplifier, vacuum-tube

This is a schematic for a very simple guitar pre-amp.  I understand the basic amplifier architecture except for those two 33k resistors in the middle, combined with the 220nF capacitor.  Any ideas as to what those are for?

[image]

Comment: I'm not real knowledgeable about tube amps, so I'll make this a comment.  [That appears to be negative feedback](http://www.angelfire.com/planet/funwithtransistors/Book_CHAP-5.html)  to control the gain and linearity.  See figure 5.6 for a circuit very much like yours.

Comment: Figure 5.11.1 is another example of negative feedback.

Comment: @crocboy: Do you already follow why the grid leak resistors exist?

Comment: Does this resemble an op amp feedback network to anyone else...?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's (capacitively coupled)negative feedback so the gain is controlled about 66K/1K = 66.

The feedback is applied to the cathode of V1a rather than the grid because it needs to be negative feedback.